bicep error whilst deploying VM Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared gallery image
I am trying to create a VM from an existing Os disk image that has been created by another module. I am getting the error below
Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared gallery image. (Code: InvalidParameter, Target: osDisk)
The code is from a decompiled arm template, I can see its missing the local login password. At this stage I am trying to get it to work to build a VM. I did some research ad found a user with a similar issue here , however the code/solution is incomplete and thus I could not follow it.
@description('The virtual machine parameter object.')
param vm object

@description('The tagging object.')
param tagging object

@description('The Network security rules ID')
param nsg_id string

@description('The Network interface card ID')
param nic_id string

@description('The managed disk ID')
param os_disk_id string


resource virtualMachines_azsdevinf001_name_resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2023-03-01' = {
  name: vm.vm_name
  location: vm.location
  tags: tagging.tags
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vm.vmSize
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        publisher: 'MicrosoftWindowsServer'
        offer: 'WindowsServer'
        sku: vm.sku
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        osType: vm.osType
        name: '${vm.vm_name}-osdisk'
        createOption: 'Attach'
        caching: 'ReadWrite'
        writeAcceleratorEnabled: false
        managedDisk: {
          id: os_disk_id
          storageAccountType: 'StandardSSD_LRS'
        }
        deleteOption: 'Detach'
      }
      dataDisks: []
    }
    
    osProfile: {
      computerName: vm.vm_name
      adminUsername: 'localadministrator'
      windowsConfiguration: {
        provisionVMAgent: true
        enableAutomaticUpdates: true
        patchSettings: {
          patchMode: 'AutomaticByPlatform'
          automaticByPlatformSettings: {
            bypassPlatformSafetyChecksOnUserSchedule: true
          }
          assessmentMode: 'AutomaticByPlatform'
          enableHotpatching: false
        }
        timeZone: 'GMT Standard Time'
        winRM: {
          listeners: []
        }
        enableVMAgentPlatformUpdates: false
      }
      secrets: []
      allowExtensionOperations: true
      requireGuestProvisionSignal: true
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic_id
          properties: {
            primary: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    diagnosticsProfile: {
      bootDiagnostics: {
        enabled: true
        storageUri: 'xxxx'
      }
    }
    licenseType: 'Windows_Server'
    priority: 'Regular'
    extensionsTimeBudget: 'PT1H30M'
  }
}


The Bicep template is trying to specify an image reference while also attaching an existing OS disk to the same virtual machine. However, these actions cannot be performed simultaneously. Try adjusting the storageProfile in your Bicep template to remove the imageReference when you set the createOption to 'Attach' for the osDisk. @learner
